# Does "espouse" imply any communication?

Tags: meaning

I often see *espouse* used in a way that might indicate the actor is communicating support (e.g. "the politician was criticized for the new position she espoused"). However, the definitions I can find only mention "to adopt or support" a particular belief or cause. Can *espouse* imply any external communication of those beliefs or positions or is it purely an internal change in mindset?

Comment: To go from believing to espousing, you gotta talk or write about that thing you believe in. I'd compare it to *aver*, *argue*, *put forth*. Even *school* or *lecture*, but more than deep thinking. Maybe you can espouse idea A that leads you to assert idea B, but I'll bet you're pretty married to idea A hidden inside of B.

Comment: Merriam-Webster has "to take up and support as a cause : become attached to", and Lexico "Adopt or support" - supporting something requires actually helping it, promoting it, cheering it, or celebrating its success. (All this is pretty much in your question, maybe you just need to think about what "support" means.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like "adopt" and "support", "espouse" can be used to refer either to someone's belief or to the expression of a belief. For example:

> Taft believed in an assertive foreign policy, but Wilson espoused more liberal ideals.

> Wilson espoused liberal ideals in the "Fourteen Points" speech that he delivered to Congress.